# Tomahawk music player 0.8.4 error message in macOS Sierra

Tags: error-handling

Trying to get Tomahawk music player to work, but i get this error message every minute:

```
Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Description: -[SPMediaKeyTap grab]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000094f00
User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc8e52b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffe1366cad objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccd0fd34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc00bf5 ___forwarding___ + 1061
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc00748 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Tomahawk                            0x0000000105f2d746 -[SPMediaKeyTap setShouldInterceptMediaKeyEvents:] + 102
6   Tomahawk                            0x0000000105f2d8d3 -[SPMediaKeyTap mediaKeyAppListChanged] + 147
7   Tomahawk                            0x0000000105f2d9ca -[SPMediaKeyTap appIsNowFrontmost:] + 234
8   Tomahawk                            0x0000000105f2d1b0 appSwitched + 48
9   HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc17e0d5 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1708
10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc17d346 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 428
11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc17d18f SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 43
12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc20f43e HIToolboxLSNotificationCallbackAllASNsFunc + 571
13  LaunchServices                      0x00007fffcddb5715 ___LSScheduleNotificationFunction_block_invoke_2 + 51
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc243ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc05424 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc04f66 __CFRunLoopRun + 1878
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffccc045b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc1a5f6c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc1a5da1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffcc1a5bd6 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
21  AppKit                              0x00007fffca89c5f5 _DPSNextEvent + 1093
22  AppKit                              0x00007fffcafac8eb -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
23  AppKit                              0x00007fffca890fbd -[NSApplication run] + 926
24  QtGui                               0x0000000109f277b7 _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 515
25  QtCore                              0x00000001097a4695 _ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 79
26  QtCore                              0x00000001097a47f3 _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 341
27  QtCore                              0x00000001097a7487 _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 199
28  Tomahawk                            0x0000000105ebc01f main + 431
29  Tomahawk                            0x0000000105ea3d64 start + 52
30  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
```

How do i stop the error message from showing?

I don't want the error window to show up every minute. I am far from a computer expert and don't know what is causing it. I have tried to configure Tomahawk music player, but the message won't leave me alone. I have already googled and looked it up, but can't find an answer to my question. I am thankful for replies that can help solve this problem.

Comment: I would love an app that plays lists from Spotify, Soundcloud and YouTube, if possible.

Comment: I think that does belong in SuperUser, StackOverflow is purely about programming. For some reason, my flag is disputed...?

Comment: Ah, sorry. You might as well delete the posts, I will try again in SuperUser.